# Automatically populate Excel rows from another sheet

Tags: excel, automation

I have an Excel document containing 2 sheets:

1. All purchases
2. Invoices

I would like to find a simple method to add items from 'All purchases' to 'Invoices' based on the date.

**Example:**

All purchases:

```
Date       | Name      | Sum
----------------------------------
2013-01-01 | Pottery   | $12.00
2013-01-01 | Liquids   | $1.00
2013-01-09 | Baby food | $12000.00  <
2013-01-02 | Car       | $12.00
2013-01-09 | Lego      | $50001.00  <
2013-01-02 | Car part  | $10000.00
2013-01-09 | More Lego | $50001.00  <
```

Based on the date 2013-01-09 I want to automatically fill the 'Invoices' in the following way:

```
Date       | Name      | Sum
----------------------------------
2013-01-09 | Baby food | $12000.00
2013-01-09 | Lego      | $50001.00
2013-01-09 | More Lego | $50001.00
```

Can this be done without macro?
I know about camera, pivot tables, lookups, indices, but I could not combine them into a usable solution.
My other plan is to look up the collection for every cell and retrieve the 1st one for the 1st row, 2nd for the 2nd row. Is there a simpler solution?

Comment: you mean you don't want to manually copy the relevant rows? it doesn't seem to involve too much effort after sorting

Comment: Are you using automation ? If there is only data manipulation, may be you could just use Sql with an OleDb connexion to the Excel file. It does not answer to your question, but there may be more options with a sql script.

Comment: The relevant rows could be anywhere and of any number. I am modifying my example to eliminate confusion.